# Conectedness in the topology of the included subset

Tags: general-topology

Considering the following family of subsets
$$T=\{U:A\subseteq U\}\cup\{\varnothing\}. $$

I have easily proved it's a topology.

How can I find its connected components and which subsets are conected?

Comment: In this topology, if $A\neq\emptyset$, the only subsets that are connected are the whole space, since any two open sets have a non-empty intersection, $A$ itself, $\emptyset$, and the singletons. Any other subset $B$ containing $a\neq b$ with $b\notin A$ will be disconnected. In fact $A\cup\{b\}$ and $A\cup(B\setminus\{b\})$ are two open sets that disconnect $B$.

Comment: If $A=\emptyset$, then the only connected subsets are $\emptyset$, and the singletons.

Comment: Be careful with the answer below. It is wrong even though it is getting voted up. The reason is that they are not applying properly the definition of connected: A topological space $X$ is called connected when there are no non-empty open sets $U_1,U_2$ such that $U_1\cup U_2=X$ and $U_1\cap U_2=\emptyset$. However, a subset $B\subset X$ is said to be connected when it is connected with respect to the subspace topology. This is, the open sets are not open sets of $X$, but sets of the form $B\cap U$ with $U$ open in $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the topology you defined by $\mathcal{T}(A)$ and note that it's also a topology (the discrete one) if $A=\emptyset$, but that $\mathcal{T}(A)$ is connected iff $A \neq \emptyset$, because then all non-empty open sets contain $A$ and so there are no disjoint non-empty sets at all, so no disconnections of $X$.

When $B$ is a subspace of $X$, it's clear that the subspace topology on $B$ induced by $\mathcal{T}(A)$ is exactly $\mathcal{T}(A\cap B)$ on $B$, so $B$ is a connected subspace iff $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ except possibly when $B$ is empty or a singleton, and then $B$ always connected, regardless of the topology on $X$.

So Qurultay's claim that all subspaces of $X$ are connected is false: e.g. $X=\Bbb N$ with $A=\{0,1,2\}$ has $B=\{3,4,5,\ldots\}$ as a discrete and thus disconnected subspace.

Comment: +1. Thanks for warning.

Comment: You just have repeated the answer of Qurultay in different symbols and claim that his/her answer is false!-1

Comment: @Khayyam he edited his answer afterwards. Look at the timeline.

Answer (score 3):

This topology is called $A$-include topology. Notice that for any open sets $U_1$ and $U_2$, $U_1\cap U_2\supseteq A$, so if $A\ne \varnothing$, then the topology is connected and there is only one component.

Also note that if $B\subset X$ is not connected, then $B=(B\cap U_1)\cup (B\cap U_2)$ with $B\cap U_1\cap U_2=\varnothing$ which shows that $B\cap A=\varnothing$. So any subset $B$ with $B\cap A=\varnothing$ is disconnected.

If $A=\varnothing$, then the topology is just discrete topology and hence totally disconnected.

Comment: A subset $B$ is said to be connected when it is connected in the subspace topology. That $U_1\cap U_2\neq \emptyset$ doesn't tell you that $B$ is connected. You need to check $B\cap U_1\cap U_2$ instead. For example, $B=\{a,b\}$ with $a\neq b$ and $a,b\notin A$ is disconnected in this topology.